# How rotate Xorg on demand with xinit?

Tags: xorg, xinit

I can physically swing around my monitor one right angle. On the console I can control orientation with the `rotate_all` "button" in /sys/devices/.../fbcon/. But xorg is not impressesed by that. Now I want to tell Xorg to start normally or rotated.

After getting several things right after `Xorg -config` (mouse and kbd now use libinput, card0 driver is "intel" not "modesetting") in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, I can start a simple window manager in X11.

```
xinit fvwm
```

I changed my xorg.conf to add a line:

```
Option "rotate" "right"
```

I was very happy for a few days: both tty and X can adapt to the tilted monitor. But now I swung back my screen to normal...and X starts wrong again! I don't want to check and (un)comment that option with every swing.

With...

```
xinit fvwm -- -screen r
```

... I was somehow able to choose a newly defined Xorg "Screen" with Identifier "r" and Monitor "rotated". But I lost it and I found out I still don't understand these screens and displays.

xrandr is good if I want to *change* the rotation.

From a rotate_all-ed tty, (with my tilted screen,) how can I configure xorg.conf so I can add "rotated" to my "xinit fvwm" command?

Now I just discover a line in section "serverlayout"...

Screen  0 "Screen0" 0 0

I don't have multihead; just one "head", occasionally tilted. How do I configure xorg.conf for that?

---

IT WAS A WRONG monitor Identifier ("DellRR" vs. "rotated" )....here is the xorg.conf, most of it. I have now two monitor and two screen sections for a rotated version.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen         0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "rotated"
    Option  "rotate" "right"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    #Driver     "modesetting"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "r"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "rotated"
EndSection
```